# jquery code seems to execute over and over

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery. The data object is either some html(used to populate a div), or its a json object for error handling.

it appears to work okay, except once i have clicked search (with error data in the search field) and then hit search again, it appears to be executing multiple times. - I have to close the alert box twice.

```
$('#search-button').click(function () {
                var query = $("#search").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Event/SearchMap/",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: ({ "query": query }),

                    success: function(data) {

                            if(data.success==false)
                            {
                                if(data.noresult)
                                {
                                    $('#span-query').text(query);
                                    alert('error');
                                }
                            }else
                            {
                                $('#event-list').empty();
                                $('#event-list').html(data);
                                load();
                            }
                     }

                });


            });
```

EDIT: When i remove the load call it behaves okay now.

so why is this causing it problems?

this is load()

```
function load() {
              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                  map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
                  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(@ViewBag.Lat, @ViewBag.Lon), @ViewBag.Zoom);
                  map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
                  map.enableScrollWheelZoom ();
                  mgr = new MarkerManager(map, { trackMarkers: true });
                  window.setTimeout(setupOfficeMarkers, 0);
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want such behavior add to $.ajax() method additional parameter: `async: false`. This will prevent parallel execution of your search requests.

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  ...
```

Comment: Not so much async, but setting a global variable to see if the ajax is already in execution.

Comment: As variant we can use ui blocking or "please wait" for such purposes. For example http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI